# Scala Spark GroupBy Aggregate maintain order of dates while sorting list

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, group-by, aggregate

```
val df = Seq((1221, 1, "Boston", "9/22/18 14:00"), (1331, 1, "New York", "8/10/18 14:00"), (1442, 1, "Toronto", "10/15/19 14:00"), (2041, 2, "LA", "1/2/18 14:00"), (2001, 2,"San Fransisco", "5/20/18 15:00"), (3001, 3, "San Jose", "6/02/18 14:00"), (3121, 3, "Seattle", "9/12/18 16:00"), (34562, 3, "Utah", "12/12/18 14:00"), (3233, 3, "Boston", "8/31/18 14:00"), (4120, 4, "Miami", "1/01/18 14:00"), (4102, 4, "Cincinati", "7/21/19 14:00"), (4201, 4, "Washington", "5/10/18 23:00"), (4301, 4, "New Jersey", "3/27/18 15:00"), (4401, 4, "Raleigh", "11/14/18 14:00")).toDF("id", "group_id", "place", "date")
```

This is a simple df

```
|   id|group_id|        place|          date|  
+-----+--------+-------------+--------------+  
| 1221|       1|       Boston| 9/22/18 14:00|  
| 1331|       1|     New York| 8/10/18 14:00|    
| 1442|       1|      Toronto|10/15/19 14:00|  
| 2041|       2|           LA|  1/2/18 14:00|  
| 2001|       2|San Fransisco| 5/20/18 15:00|  
| 3001|       3|     San Jose| 6/02/18 14:00|  
| 3121|       3|      Seattle| 9/12/18 16:00|  
| 4562|       3|         Utah|12/12/18 14:00|  
| 3233|       3|       Boston| 8/31/18 14:00|  
| 4120|       4|        Miami| 1/01/18 14:00|  
| 4102|       4|    Cincinati| 7/21/19 14:00|  
| 4201|       4|   Washington| 5/10/18 23:00|  
| 4301|       4|   New Jersey| 3/27/18 15:00|  
| 4401|       4|      Raleigh|11/14/18 14:00|  
+-----+--------+-------------+--------------+
```

I want to group by "group_id" and collect dates in ascending order. (earliest date first).

Needed output :

```
+--------+----+--------+--------------+----+-------------+--------------+----+----------+--------------+----+---------+--------------+
|group_id|id_1| venue_1|        date_1|id_2|      venue_2|        date_2|id_3|   venue_3|        date_3|id_4|  venue_4|        date_4|
+--------+----+--------+--------------+----+-------------+--------------+----+----------+--------------+----+---------+--------------+
|       1|1331|New York|08/10/18 14:00|1221|       Boston|09/22/18 14:00|1442|   Toronto|10/15/19 14:00|null|     null|          null|
|       3|3001|San Jose|06/02/18 14:00|3233|       Boston|08/31/18 14:00|3121|   Seattle|09/12/18 16:00|4562|     Utah|12/12/18 14:00|
|       4|4120|   Miami|01/01/18 14:00|4301|   New Jersey|03/27/18 15:00|4201|Washington|05/10/18 23:00|4102|Cincinati|07/21/19 14:00|
|       2|2041|      LA| 01/2/18 14:00|2001|San Fransisco|05/20/18 15:00|null|      null|          null|null|     null|          null|
+--------+----+--------+--------------+----+-------------+--------------+----+----------+--------------+----+---------+--------------+
```

The code i am using:

```
//for sorting by date to preserve order
val df2 = df.repartition(col("group_id")).sortWithinPartitions("date")

val finalDF = df2.groupBy(df("group_id")).agg(collect_list(df("id")).alias("id_list"),collect_list(df("place")).alias("venue_name_list"),collect_list(df("date")).alias("date_list")).selectExpr("group_id","id_list[0] as id_1","venue_name_list[0] as venue_1","date_list[0] as date_1","id_list[1] as id_2","venue_name_list[1] as venue_2","date_list[1] as date_2","id_list[2] as id_3","venue_name_list[2] as venue_3","date_list[2] as date_3","id_list[3] as id_4","venue_name_list[3] as venue_4","date_list[3] as date_4")
```

But the output is :

```
+--------+-----+-------+--------------+----+-------------+--------------+----+----------+-------------+----+----------+-------------+
|group_id| id_1|venue_1|        date_1|id_2|      venue_2|        date_2|id_3|   venue_3|       date_3|id_4|   venue_4|       date_4|
+--------+-----+-------+--------------+----+-------------+--------------+----+----------+-------------+----+----------+-------------+
|       1| 1442|Toronto|10/15/19 14:00|1331|     New York| 8/10/18 14:00|1221|    Boston|9/22/18 14:00|null|      null|         null|
|       3|34562|   Utah|12/12/18 14:00|3001|     San Jose| 6/02/18 14:00|3233|    Boston|8/31/18 14:00|3121|   Seattle|9/12/18 16:00|
|       4| 4120|  Miami| 1/01/18 14:00|4401|      Raleigh|11/14/18 14:00|4301|New Jersey|3/27/18 15:00|4201|Washington|5/10/18 23:00|
|       2| 2041|     LA|  1/2/18 14:00|2001|San Fransisco| 5/20/18 15:00|null|      null|         null|null|      null|         null|
+--------+-----+-------+--------------+----+-------------+--------------+----+----------+-------------+----+----------+-------------+
```

Observation: 
if the dates are formatted instead of example "9/22/18 14:00" to "09/22/18 14:00", adding a '0' ahead of single digit month dates and adding zero ahead of single digit dates, the code works properly, that is, the dates orders are maintained properly. Any solution is welcome! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As you've already figured out sorting by unformatted `StringType` dates is the root of the problem, here's one approach that first generates `TimestampType` dates, create a `StructType` column of the wanted columns in "suitable field order" for sorting:

```
val finalDF = df.
  withColumn("dateFormatted", to_timestamp($"date", "MM/dd/yy HH:mm")).
  groupBy($"group_id").agg(
    sort_array(collect_list(struct($"dateFormatted", $"id", $"place"))).as("sorted_arr")
  ).
  selectExpr(
    "group_id",
    "sorted_arr[0].id as id_1", "sorted_arr[0].place as venue_1", "sorted_arr[0].dateFormatted as date_1",
    "sorted_arr[1].id as id_2", "sorted_arr[1].place as venue_2", "sorted_arr[1].dateFormatted as date_2",
    "sorted_arr[2].id as id_3", "sorted_arr[2].place as venue_3", "sorted_arr[2].dateFormatted as date_3",
    "sorted_arr[3].id as id_4", "sorted_arr[3].place as venue_4", "sorted_arr[3].dateFormatted as date_4"
  )

finalDF.show
// +--------+----+--------+-------------------+----+-------------+-------------------+----+----------+-------------------+-----+-------+-------------------+
// |group_id|id_1| venue_1|             date_1|id_2|      venue_2|             date_2|id_3|   venue_3|             date_3| id_4|venue_4|             date_4|
// +--------+----+--------+-------------------+----+-------------+-------------------+----+----------+-------------------+-----+-------+-------------------+
// |       1|1331|New York|2018-08-10 14:00:00|1221|       Boston|2018-09-22 14:00:00|1442|   Toronto|2019-10-15 14:00:00| null|   null|               null|
// |       3|3001|San Jose|2018-06-02 14:00:00|3233|       Boston|2018-08-31 14:00:00|3121|   Seattle|2018-09-12 16:00:00|34562|   Utah|2018-12-12 14:00:00|
// |       4|4120|   Miami|2018-01-01 14:00:00|4301|   New Jersey|2018-03-27 15:00:00|4201|Washington|2018-05-10 23:00:00| 4401|Raleigh|2018-11-14 14:00:00|
// |       2|2041|      LA|2018-01-02 14:00:00|2001|San Fransisco|2018-05-20 15:00:00|null|      null|               null| null|   null|               null|
// +--------+----+--------+-------------------+----+-------------+-------------------+----+----------+-------------------+-----+-------+-------------------+
```

A couple of notes:

1. Forming the `StructType` column is necessary to make sure corresponding columns will be sorted together
2. Struct field `dateFormatted` is placed first so that `sort_array` will sort the array in the wanted order

Comment: partitioning and sorting does not always give the same result in an maintained order. even after converting it to TimeStamptype.

Comment: @saurin shah, please see revised answer to address the said issue.

Comment: this did help. But i still found cases where order isnt maintained for a larger dataset. Probably it is not supported in SPARK 2.1 version.

Comment: @saurin shah, I would examine the rows (particularly values of `dataFormatted`) that aren't in order.  If the original date strings aren't all in the "MM/dd/yy HH:mm" format, some `dataFormatted` will be incorrect and ordering will be off.

Comment: yes. probably that is the reason why the ordering is off. i will check the strings format for the date. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Format the date using to_timestamp function and sorting in the aggregation using sort_array like this:

```
 import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.to_timestamp

  val df = Seq((1221, 1, "Boston", "9/22/18 14:00"), (1331, 1, "New York", "8/10/18 14:00"), (1442, 1, "Toronto", "10/15/19 14:00"), (2041, 2, "LA", "1/2/18 14:00"), (2001, 2, "San Fransisco", "5/20/18 15:00"), (3001, 3, "San Jose", "6/02/18 14:00"), (3121, 3, "Seattle", "9/12/18 16:00"), (34562, 3, "Utah", "12/12/18 14:00"), (3233, 3, "Boston", "8/31/18 14:00"), (4120, 4, "Miami", "1/01/18 14:00"), (4102, 4, "Cincinati", "7/21/19 14:00"), (4201, 4, "Washington", "5/10/18 23:00"), (4301, 4, "New Jersey", "3/27/18 15:00"), (4401, 4, "Raleigh", "11/14/18 14:00"))
    .toDF("id", "group_id", "place", "date")

  val df2 = df.withColumn("MyDate", to_timestamp($"date", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"))

  val finalDF = df2.groupBy(df("group_id"))
    .agg(collect_list(df2("id")).alias("id_list"),
      collect_list(df2("place")).alias("venue_name_list"),
      sort_array(collect_list(df2("MyDate"))).alias("date_list")).
    selectExpr("group_id",
      "id_list[0] as id_1",
      "venue_name_list[0] as venue_1",
      "date_list[0] as date_1",
      "id_list[1] as id_2",
      "venue_name_list[1] as venue_2",
      "date_list[1] as date_2",
      "id_list[2] as id_3",
      "venue_name_list[2] as venue_3",
      "date_list[2] as date_3",
      "id_list[3] as id_4",
      "venue_name_list[3] as venue_4",
      "date_list[3] as date_4")


  finalDF.show()
```

Comment: awesome. BUT the order is **not** maintained for a larger data set. partitioning and sorting does not always give the same result in an maintained order. probably this method can. but even this **does not**. thank you.